# How to implement the haskell `\\` function?

Tags: haskell, lisp, set, clisp

In haskell, `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] \\ [4,5,6]` will return `[1,2,3,7]`.  Now i want to implement the same function using clisp. Up to now i find `set-difference` works :

```
(set-difference '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7) '(4 5 6))
```

Are there any other solution ?

Comment: Maybe you can explain what's wrong with using a function called "set-difference" to find the difference of two sets. What do you actually want?

Comment: Looking at the edits, I think z_axis might have meant his `set-difference` addition to be a solution to his problem.  I think Chris Morgan's attempt to help may have obscured that intent.

Comment: I am not used to regard a list as a set.

Answer (score 3):

Here are relevant bits of haskell library source. Maybe you can translate these definitions directly. I don't think it uses anything specific to Haskell.

(the source is from http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Data-List.html)

```
delete                  :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
delete                  =  deleteBy (==)

-- | The 'deleteBy' function behaves like 'delete', but takes a
-- user-supplied equality predicate.
deleteBy                :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> a -> [a] -> [a]
deleteBy _  _ []        = []
deleteBy eq x (y:ys)    = if x `eq` y then ys else y : deleteBy eq x ys

(\\)                    :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
(\\)                    =  foldl (flip delete)
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know Common Lisp that well, so here's a Scheme implementation of the code pasted by Ben:

```lisp
(define (difference big small)
  (fold delete big small))

(define (delete x lst)
  (delete-by equal? x lst))

(define (delete-by equal? x lst)
  (if (null? lst) '()
      (receive (y ys) (car+cdr lst)
        (if (equal? x y) ys
            (cons y (delete-by equal? x ys))))))
```

where `fold` and `car+cdr` come from [SRFI 1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html), and `receive` comes from [SRFI 8](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-8/srfi-8.html).

---

If we will allow ourselves the use of [SRFI 26](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-26/srfi-26.html)'s `cut` form, then we have a solution that looks even closer to the Haskell version (since the latter uses currying in at least two places):

```lisp
(define difference (cut fold delete <...>))
(define delete (cut delete-by equal? <...>))

; Unchanged from the above version
(define (delete-by equal? x lst)
  (if (null? lst) '()
      (receive (y ys) (car+cdr lst)
        (if (equal? x y) ys
            (cons y (delete-by equal? x ys))))))
```